# Is the flag treated as string in c command argument?

Tags: c

say I have the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (argv[1] == "-s") {
        printf("success\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("failed\n");
    }

return 0;
}
```

In the shell as I ran the executable file it prints `failed`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you can't do string comparison in C with `==` or `!=` because those compare the base address, rather than the actual content. To properly compare the string in C you have to use `strcmp`.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes.

Your biggest mistake is that you should be using [strcmp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) or [strncmp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncmp) to properly compare strings in C.

**Bonus points:** loop through `argv[]` and use `printf` to display each element to see for yourself what gets placed where.